# link_to to root_path with additional parameters is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

On my root page in Ruby on Rails application, I want to have a link to the root_path with an additional parameter:

```
 <%= link_to t('3_days'), root_path(range: '3_days') %>
```

When I click this link, nothing happens, the page is not refreshed.
I'm using Ruby on Rails 6 with Turbolinks, how can I fix this?

Comment: Add this to your link_to, data: { turbolinks: false }

Answer (score 2):

If you're already on the root_path, try it:

```
 <%= link_to t('3_days'), url_for(range: '3_days') %>
```